# TableViewController Header Cell Order Data Retrieval Issue (SWIFT Language)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to implement a function where the user clicks on the profileImage , they will be sent to the correct profileView if passed in the correct profileId.

**Problem:** When clicking on the current profileImage , I always get the profile of another host who's 1 index away from the current host. This isn't clear so I will use pictures to demonstrate my problem.

Screen 1:

[image]

*clicks on first profile picture*

Screen 2:

[image]

*gets the profile of person 2*

For the ProfileViewController to know what profile it needs to show , I passed the profileId in the prepare for segue function.

**Code:**

Grabbing ProfileId:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let sectionHeaderView : HeaderTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SectionHeaderCell") as! HeaderTableViewCell
    let event : PFObject = self.objects![section] as! PFObject
    let user : PFUser = event["hostUser"] as! PFUser 
    let hostID : String = user.objectId!
    hostId = hostID
    return sectionHeaderView
}
```

*Passing profileId to the next ViewController: *

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "feedToEvent"){
        let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! EventViewController
        destinationViewController.eventID = eventId
        destinationViewController.eventHost = hostId
    }
```

**Thoughts**

The event id passes in fine , it's only the profileId that's the problem. For grabbing the eventId , I use cellForRowAtIndexPath function instead of viewForHeaderInSection. Is that the reason why? Any suggestions for a solution would be great!

Comment: Disliking the post without commenting the flaws does not help. If you are going to dislike , please let me know what is wrong with it.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but I'd imagine you would need to provide the initializer code and a better explanation of how the host information is populated in order to narrow down a potential cause for your issue. I threw out some guesses, but I'd be happy to help more if you still haven't tracked down the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would print out the profile id you are setting for the user in the header, and then print out the one you are using to populate the controller. Verify they are the same number.

If you are storing the hosts or events in an array, ensure there are no off-by-one errors due to 0 index.

Perhaps it might be easier just to store the eventId, then lookup the host id from the event object in your Parse table?

If there are more than one section on this table, it is likely that hostId will only ever be set with the last id in the table. If the one you click on is different from the last one saved, you will probably load the same profile every time.

One trick might be to set the tag on the button to the id of the host profile you want to load when it is fired. So in the button handler, you could just set the id to whatever the sender.tag value and always load the correct profile. If it's not a number, you could use AccessibilityIdentifiers

Comment: Thank you for your insightful comment. I decided to go with storing the eventId and look up the host id from the event object. I never thought of that. :)

Comment: I tried the eventId to look up hostId and it didn't work. That's very odd.  I'll try your tag trick and I'll let you know if I have success with that. Thank you!

Comment: Let me know if you need any help, i'd be happy to. If it does work, feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: I tried the tag and it didn't work. This is a strange behavior and I'm curious to why it's doing that. I also removed the header and placed everything in the cell body and the same results.

Comment: Did you try printing the host id when you set it, and then again when you click on it, and evaluate if they match?

Comment: I found another solution which was to create a new button class that keeps track of the section index. The downside is that users won't be able to click on the picture(since it already has a PFImage class assigned to it). They'll need to click on the username itself. Hahaha , another problem for another day , but thank you!

Comment: You could put a container around both of type UIControl, and then have the whole container act as the button

Comment: Great thinking. I will do that!